# cannot import OpenCV in a Docker container in Raspberry Pi

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a Docker container that can run Python OpenCV code in Raspbian 10.

```
FROM python:3.5-buster
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apt-utils -y
RUN apt-get install python-opencv -y
RUN apt-get install python3-opencv -y
COPY a.py /
CMD ["python3", "a.py"]
```

`a.py` is simply `import cv2`

When I run the container, I got the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three workarounds:

- Use `debian:buster` as your base container instead of `python:3.5-buster`

or

- Put this into your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

or

- Similarly, put this at the top of `a.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')

import cv2
```

It's unclear why Python's package path system is so fragile, but the last two are a variation of suggestions on a similar question<sup>[1]</sup>, and among the quickest workarounds I could verify.

<sup>[1]</sup> [Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

Comment: Thank you very much.  The 1st method works.  But not the 2nd method.